# How do I make my string a hyperlink that can redirect to another website

Tags: java, android

```
public void whenClick(View v){
    LatLng Maharashtra = new LatLng(19.169257, 73.341601);
    String url = "google";
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Maharashtra).title("Maharashtra").snippet("link");
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Maharashtra));
```

Does anybodyknow how to make it so that when I click the link string it redirects the user to a website

Comment: Sounds like you should display a WebView inside the marker pop-up

Comment: how do i do this

Comment: Make an InfoWindowAdapter https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#custom_info_windows